# Join 3 database tables to get JSON Result in laravel

Tags: mysql, json, laravel-4, jsonresult

I have 3 database tables : Country,City and Restaurant

```
Country     {id,name}
City        {id,name,country_id}
Restaurant  {id,name,city_id}
```

how can I retrieve country info with it's cities and it's restaurants ?

I'm using this code to get the countries with it's cities:
note that I made all relationships between the tables as follows:

```
Country {hasMany('City')}
City    {hasMany('Hotel')}
City    {belongsTo('Country')}
Hotel   {belongsTo('City')}

$x = Country::with('city')->get();
return Response::json($x,200,[],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Spain",
        "city": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Madrid",
                "country_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Barcelona",
                "country_id": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Italy",
        "city": []
    }
]
```

what shall I do to get the restaurants in each city in the same JSON response?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hasManyThrough()` to access distant relationships:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

```
// App\Country
public function hotels() {
    $this->hasManyThrough('App\Hotel', 'App\City');
}
```

then you can fetch it like so:

```
$x = Country::with('city')->with('hotels')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. but how can I get all hotels only within a country @maximl337?

Comment: `$x=Country->with("city")->with("hotels")->where("country", "=" , "US")->get();
`$hotels = $x->hotels;

  If you want to filters hotels as well

`$hotels = $x->hotels()->where("city_id" , "=", 15)->get();